# From List to int. Unable to convert a query result

Tags: java, mysql, arraylist, sap-commerce-cloud

I have this query:

```
select count(*) from {Order as or join CustomerOrderStatus as os on
{or:CustomerOrderStatus}={os:pk} join OrderEntry as oe on
{or.pk}={oe.order} join PurchaseAmount as pa on
{or.pointOfSale}={pa.purchaseAmountOwner} join PurchaseAmountTimeSlice
as ts on {pa.pk}={ts.purchaseamount}} where {or:company} in
(8796093710341) and {or:pointOfSale} in (8796097413125)
```

I have this code in Java to retrieve result:

```
FlexibleSearchQuery query = new FlexibleSearchQuery(queryBuilder.toString());
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
result = getFlexibleSearchService().<Integer> search(query).getResult();
```

I want to take the int value of the count from the result list.
If I write `result.get(0)` I obtain an error `IllegalArgumentException`:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid pks [4] - unknown typecode 0
    at de.hybris.platform.core.WrapperFactory.getCachedItems(WrapperFactory.java:304)
    at de.hybris.platform.core.LazyLoadItemList.loadPage(LazyLoadItemList.java:230)
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.impl.LazyLoadModelList.loadPage(LazyLoadModelList.java:60)
    at de.hybris.platform.core.LazyLoadItemList.switchPage(LazyLoadItemList.java:219)
    at de.hybris.platform.core.LazyLoadItemList.switchBufferedPageNoLock(LazyLoadItemList.java:475)
    at de.hybris.platform.core.LazyLoadItemList.switchBufferedPageSynchronized(LazyLoadItemList.java:467)
    at de.hybris.platform.core.LazyLoadItemList.switchBufferedPage(LazyLoadItemList.java:462)
    at de.hybris.platform.core.LazyLoadItemList.getOrSwitchBufferedPage(LazyLoadItemList.java:453)
    at de.hybris.platform.core.LazyLoadItemList.getOrSwitchBufferedPage(LazyLoadItemList.java:433)
    at de.hybris.platform.core.LazyLoadItemList.getBuffered(LazyLoadItemList.java:111)
    at de.hybris.platform.core.LazyLoadItemList.get(LazyLoadItemList.java:97)
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:358)
    at de.hybris.platform.core.internal.BaseLazyLoadItemList$1.next(BaseLazyLoadItemList.java:180)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray(AbstractCollection.java:195)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.toArray(Collections.java:1059)
```

How I can get the int value?

Comment: When you ask about an exception, always post the stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved in this way:

```
private FlexibleSearchService flexibleSearchService;

    @Override
    public void onValidate(PurchaseAmountTimeSliceModel paramMODEL, InterceptorContext paramInterceptorContext)
        throws InterceptorException {

       //.....
       final StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        queryBuilder.append("select {ts.pk}");
        queryBuilder.append(
                " from {Order as or join CustomerOrderStatus as os on {or:CustomerOrderStatus}={os:pk} join OrderEntry as oe on {or.pk}={oe.order} ");
        queryBuilder.append(
                "join PurchaseAmount as pa on {or.pointOfSale}={pa.purchaseAmountOwner} join PurchaseAmountTimeSlice as ts on {pa.pk}={ts.purchaseamount}} where ");

        if (pointOfSale != null && company != null) {
            queryBuilder.append("{or:company} in (" + company.getPk() + ") and {or:pointOfSale} in ("
                    + pointOfSale.getPk() + ")");
        }
        FlexibleSearchQuery query = new FlexibleSearchQuery(queryBuilder.toString());
        SearchResult<PurchaseAmountTimeSliceModel> result = flexibleSearchService.search(query);

        if (result != null) {
            if (result.getCount() >= 10) {
                LOG.error("There's already 10 purchase amount time slices configured. You reached the limit.");
                throw new InterceptorException(
                        "There's already 10 purchase amount time slices configured. You reached the limit.");
            }
        }
    //.....
```

The solution is similar ;)

Comment: " + company.getPk() + " is subject to a SQL Injection attack

Answer (score 2):

Replace `count(*)` with `count({or:Pk})` and set result class of flexible search query to `Integer` like this `query.setResultClassList(Collections.singletonList(Integer.class));`